# Sending data on serial port using Android Emulator

Tags: android, serial-port, emulation

I want to send/receive data through serial port using Android Emulator but not able to do so. I configured virtual serial ports (tnto,tnt1....). tnt0 and tnt1 are connected, so any data sent on tnt0 will be received on tnt1 and now I launched emulator with serial port tnto:
    emulator -qemu -serial /dev/tnto

Now I installed some serial port APP when I am trying to connect/configure any of the serial port APP(like SerialPort.apk,DroidTerm.apk, serialbot.apk etc) the APP is crashing. Can someone help me here ? I just want to communicate with serial port using Android emulator.

Comment: I am getting following error : 10-25 17:36:51.365  1533  1667 I ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=android_serialport_api.sample/.SerialPortPreferences} from uid 10059 on display 0
10-25 17:36:51.419  2657  2657 D SerialPort: Found new driver g_serial on /dev/ttyGS
10-25 17:36:51.419  2657  2657 D SerialPort: Found new driver serial on /dev/ttyS

Comment: 10-25 17:36:51.420  2657  2657 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-25 17:36:51.420  2657  2657 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 17:36:51.420  2657  2657 E AndroidRuntime: Process: android_serialport_api.sample, PID: 2657
10-25 17:36:51.420  2657  2657 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android_serialport_api.sample/android_serialport_api.sample.SerialPortPreferences}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

Answer (score 0):

check your code for NullPointerException rather than serail port.